# How can I make multiple monitors go to standby independently?

Tags: multiple-monitors, power-management, monitor

I have a two-monitor setup. One monitor I use all the time, the other sometimes. I find myself switching the second monitor on and off quite frequently, so as not to be distracted by its contents.

Is there any software under Ubuntu that can intelligently measure idle time independently on multiple monitors. For example, if nothing has changed in a screen (no window mapped or focussed, nothing drawn, pointer not moved into that screen), then it should count as idle.